# Devise strong_params on Nested attributes form

Tags: forms, devise, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-6, accepts-nested-attributes

I am following this tutorial [https://kakimotonline.com/2014/03/30/extending-devise-registrations-controller/][1], whose purpose is creating a Devise User, and its owning Company on the same form.

Models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

end
```

```
user model has a reerence to company :
add_reference(:users, :company, {:foreign_key=>true})
```

I was surprised to see that the 'belonged' can have the accepts_nested mention (thought only the owner could)

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 
  has_one :user
 
end
```

The form view is :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
      <%= company_form.text_field :cnpj  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The registration controller is created to substitute the default one :

```
**controllers/registrations_controller.rb**
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 
  def new
    build_resource({})
    self.resource.company = Company.new
    respond_with self.resource
  end
  
  def create
    @user = User.new sign_up_params
    @user.save
  end
end
```

strong_prams permission :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, company_attributes: [:name])
    end
  end
end
```

with this route

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
 
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
 
end
```

On the console, I can create instances :

```
User.create(email:'test@gmail.com',
            password:'password',
            password_confirmation:'password',
            company_attributes: { name: 'nours' })
```

creates one user, and his associated company :)

But the form fails in the #create :
. The route works, the params are OK, #create retrieves the right permitted values,

````
=>{"email"=>"tota@gmal.com", "password"=>"zigzig", "password_confirmation"=>"zigzig", "company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"tata toto"}}```
but creation of instance 
```>> User.new(sign_up_params) 
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, company_id: nil>```, 
the same with 
```>> build_resource sign_up_params  
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, company_id: nil>```

What's wrong with strong_params ?


  [1]: https://kakimotonline.com/2014/03/30/extending-devise-registrations-controller/
````

Answer (score 1):

The reason you’re getting this error is because you have `belongs_to :company` in your user model. This means there has to be a company or the user won’t save. Try changing it to `belongs_to :company, optional: true`.

Starting with Rails 5.0, “all model’s `belongs_to` associations are now treated as if the `required: true` option is present”. You can find out more [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34454).

Comment: thank you @hashrocket , I've already fixed this 'optional/required' part. My problem now is on the strong_params ^^ I've made some changes on my question

Comment: In the future, you should create a new question rather than change the question. This way, others will benefit from both questions.